# How to change CheckboxListTile height?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Shortly, I need the selectable area to be smaller in terms of height.

Text and Checkbox sizes are good, but the surrounding box is too big for the checklist I'm trying to create.

[CheckBoxListTile current height vs. desired height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NTJy.png)

Tried wrapping it with Transform.scale but text becomes too small:

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.8,
  child: CheckboxListTile(
    title: const Text("Rinite alérgica"),
    value: timeDilation != 1.0,
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
    onChanged: (bool value) {
      setState(() {
      timeDilation = value ? 2.0 : 1.0;
      });
    },
  ),
),
```

Tried wrapping it with Container, but I get on-screen overflow warnings.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When trying to resize the `CheckboxListFile` it seems that Google actually recommends creating a custom Tile widget and making use of the `Checkbox` widget.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html#material.CheckboxListTile.3

Look at the LabeledCheckbox widget that's been created. You can very easily modify all components to fit your needs. For example, if you wished to make the Widget itself smaller, you can now wrap it in a Container

```
/// Flutter code sample for CheckboxListTile

// ![Custom checkbox list tile sample](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/material/checkbox_list_tile_custom.png)
//
// Here is an example of a custom LabeledCheckbox widget, but you can easily
// make your own configurable widget.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LabeledCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const LabeledCheckbox({
    Key key,
    @required this.label,
    @required this.padding,
    @required this.value,
    @required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onChanged(!value);
      },
      child: Container(
        padding: padding,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Text(label)),
            Checkbox(
              value: value,
              onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                onChanged(newValue);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool _isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LabeledCheckbox(
      label: 'This is the label text',
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      value: _isSelected,
      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
        setState(() {
          _isSelected = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
SizedBox(
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  child: ......
)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer :). Tried it just now, [this is the result](https://imgur.com/a/Za2wepw). It's close to what I want, all that's left is figuring out how to centralize vertically the checkbox and the text. Wrapping CheckboxListTile with Padding and using EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20) inside SizedBox [provides the following outcome](https://imgur.com/a/olIBCp5).

Comment: i just add the Card for no reason at all.
``````
SizedBox(height: 60, width: 230,
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 10.0,
                    child: CheckboxListTile(
                      title: const Text("Rinite alérgica"),
                      value: true,
                      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
``````
this looks [link](https://i.imgur.com/9Q4vPuF.png) like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am sorry for taking so long to give you feedback, my week was kind of rough. Upon changing the height value, your suggestion [looks like this](https://imgur.com/a/F8FMH4M). Still doesn't center vertically :(

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/9Q4vPuF.png) mine looks ok though;

Comment: Yes indeed! But suppose you wanted to make it [this big](https://i.imgur.com/c0WkH1J.png). How would you do it? That's my question :P

Comment: whats the height and width you are currently using?